# eclipse method names with parenthesises

Tags: eclipse, content-assist

[image]

[image]

Content assist insert method names with parenthesises after pressing enter. Can I disable such inserting. I'd like that method name is inserted without brackets.

Comment: Why do you want that? Perhaps these is a different way to accomplish your objective ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. [the Java content assist preferences](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/preferences/java/editor/ref-preferences-content-assist.htm) have an option to turn off the arguments, but you still get the parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple solution:
Just define a variable such as

String setVisible; !

Now you can use the Eclipse content assist to insert
the full Variable (Method) without brackets.

When you finish editing just comment the variable out or delete it.

Maybe you can find a table with all jFrame Methods or assemble one for your own